# "RelativeSource" binding for Knockout template bindings (similar to WPF)

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to implement something similar to the WPF concept of RelativeSource bindings for templates in Knockout, in particular the RelativeSource with its mode set to [TemplatedParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

I have implemented this by overriding the default KO template binding to add $templatedParent to the binding context, as per the code snippet below.

```
 var originalInit = ko.bindingHandlers.template.init,
     originalUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.template.update;

 ko.bindingHandlers.template = {
     init: originalInit,
     update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         bindingContext['$templateElement'] = element;
         originalUpdate(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
     }
 };
```

This allows the child elements created by the template binding can then use in their `data-bind` attributes, for example  -

```
data-bind="style: {backgroundColor: $templateElement.fillColor}"
```

This solution presumes that the template parent element implements a property called `fillColor` that can be data bound (which I can achieve by making it a web component custom element, and exposing the property as a ko observable).

I am wondering

1. if anyone else has done something similar to this and
2. whether from a design perspective this is a bad idea

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: I'd say why not. But this might be a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than here

Comment: You could achieve the same a lot easier if you just add a property on the viewmodel and bind both elements to that property. This would also decouple the two elements from each other, making it possible to change one without having to change the other, as long as the viewmodel property stays the same (and a view is supposed to have a dependency on its viewmodel anyway).

Comment: I disagree Robert - I am building a web component in which I want to create separation of its visualization from its API or behaviour - the binding isn't connecting two disparate elements in a view or SPA, it is translating a purely visual property (eg a level fill color) set on the top level object (eg a linear gauge) and poking that value into one (or more) of the visuals that make up the visual template of that top level object. I want the "widget" to be self contained, and not have to rely on a view model to transfer purely visual properties from the top level object into its parts.